# Getting Error while connecting public to private server on Oracle cloud

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, oracle, bastion

```
ssh -t -o ProxyCommand='ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa opc@0.0.0.0 -W %h:%p %r' -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa opc@0.0.0.0

ssh -t -o ProxyCommand='ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa opc@<publiIP> -W %h:%p %r' -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa opc@privateIP
```

From the first command I am getting output 1 :

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

From the second command I am getting output 2 :

> ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub not found

Please help me to resolve this. I have created RSA public and private keys using putty.

Answer (score 0):

The first version looks hinky, with the 0.0.0.0 being a non-valid IP address. But perhaps that's a cloudy thing?

The second version looks better. Run it with "-v" before the "-t" and it will show you the enterpolated proxy command. Something like:

```
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa opc@<publiIP> -W privateip:22 opc
```

Now, run the command after the word "exec":

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa opc@<publiIP> -W privateip:22 opc
```

and see what error it shows. That'll tell you what you need to fix. I'm guessing you don't have a private key in the file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.